# How to call echo inside URL include?

Tags: javascript, php, echo

I want to do this: 
`<?php include_once ("includes/'<?php echo $mymodule1; ?>'.php"); ?>`

I try before with:
`<?php include_once ("includes/'.echo $mymodule1.'.php"); ?>`

But not work :(

You can help me?, many thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

include_once isn't really a function. Only kind of.

Putting a variable in a string:

```php
include_once "includes/{$mymodule1}.php";
```

Comment: Thanks my friend :)

Answer (score 0):

Write down the variable without the `echo` statement. Either do this:

```
<?php include_once ("includes/" . $mymodule1 . ".php"); ?>
```

or this:

```
<?php include_once ("includes/$mymodule1.php"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly put the variable , no need for echo here

```php
<?php 
include_once('includes/'.$yourvar.'.php');
?>
```